# How to make sections of image glow on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, imagemap

I will be making a website for a man that is involved with a local legion. He's restored military regiment photos. He wants to hover on each person in the photo, have the outline of them glow, and a tool tip of their name, and/or link to further down the page to more details of them.

I've used image mapping before, and the website I use has poly mapping (www.image-maps.com), which would result in me outlining every person in this photo individually. I'm fine with doing that, but would it be easier to do that in photoshop and have some sort of map that when you hover over that person, it replaces the image to the photoshopped one with a glow?

I've tried to research this, and have come across a lot of different things, but nothing super similar. 
There's a US map that's essentially what I want it to do:
http://stommepoes.nl/Menus/maphover.html
http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/examples/usa.html

But I'm not sure how to go about making that custom, and not just a map of the US.

Any recommendations would be great. Just not really sure what the best route is for this to save time and effort.

Thanks!

Comment: I used imagemapster for many project (that are very different for US map) and it works very well, it's definatly one of the best (and easiest) API to use for this.

Comment: @YannChabot Thanks! http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/default.aspx?demos.html#vegetables This demo may be the way I'll go.

Comment: My pleasure! Said it as an answer and added you a good plugin to make it easier for you to have your path!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you to go for this:

http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/examples/usa.html

Very good plugin, then you have to make an HTML map areas. If you have photoshop, I strongly recommand you this plugin. With those both, it's very easy to make your path in photoshop and then get the Coords for your HTML map

https://creative.adobe.com/addons/products/2389#.Vl83pXYvdhE

I did miracles pretty quickly with those tools.

Hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

You will need as many versions of your image as there are people, with each version having one person glowing. Then use [css transitions](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/) to fade between images, then [html map areas](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp) to control which areas call the corresponding highlighted image.

Comment: There's around 130 people in the picture. I'm concerned about load time at that point. But that does seem like the easiest thing to do.

Comment: This is a very bad idea it will take you forever lol

Comment: Ok 130 is quite a lot. This is a programmer answer, not a plugin answer : you could create a png mask, much bigger than the image, with a little bit of grey and a little bit of opacity, then put a small circle in the middle, transparent, you get the idea. Then you just need a little script to position your mask, the circle over the chosen person, as the user mouses over. Nothing to it.